# Where can I obtain ICANN's DNS list?

Tags: dns, internet

Suppose that I wanted to host my own DNS server based on the presumption that for whatever reason, I am unable to access ICANN's personal servers. Is there some sort of hosts file, or global DNS that I can download with the list of currently indexed and assigned addresses, and if so, where can I obtain this?

I'm pretty new to network administration, so bear with me. I haven't undertaken a task like this before. Most I've done before is screwed around with my Hosts file.

Comment: Could you clarify the part on a "list of currently indexed and assigned addresses"? First of all, DNS is about domain names, not (IP) addresses. And are you actually looking for *all* domains?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the [root.zone](ftp://rs.internic.net/domain/root.zone) file would provide what you are looking for.  It contains all of the recognized [Top Level Domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Internet_top-level_domains) (.com, .net, .gov, .us, .ru, .cn, etc), along with the name servers IP addresses that service those TLDs.

Keep in mind the root.zone file only gets you one layer deep.  As others have pointed out, DNS is a hierarchical, distributed database.  There is no central list of every IP address in the world (not feasible).

Say you wanted to go to www.example.com.  Your computer needs to know the destination IP address.  Using the root.zone file, you would be able to identify the nameservers responsible for all .com domains.  Your computer then has to ask the .com nameservers how to resolve example.com.  The .com nameservers will help you identify the servers responsible for all example.com sites.  Your computer then has to ask the example.com name servers for the IP address of www.example.com.

If you don't trust ICANN much, how much do you trust the registrars that are responsible for maintaining the various TLDs?

Note that in the real world, no one ever uses root.zone directly, and it can go out of date at any time.  Instead, there are ["root hints" servers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_name_server) that you can query to get this information.

You would not be the first person to have issues with ownership of the root nameservers.  Alternate sets of root DNS servers exist.  If you are running your own DNS server on your network, you could simply swap out your root hints with [this list](http://www.orsn.org/en/tech/).

Answer (score 0):

You mean the [root.hints](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/files) file? There is no database for all addresses / domains. DNS is a distributed Database.

Let's use **networkengineering.stackexchange.com** as an example. Assume there is a . at the end.

If your DNS server hasn’t cached the answer it will ask one of the root servers **.** for the **com** name server. After that your DNS server asks the **.com** name server for the **stackexchange** name server and then will ask the **stackexchange** name server for **networkengineering**.

If your running Linux install **dig** and see for yourself with *dig networkengineering.stackexchange.com +trace*

(It's always a good idea to have dig installed when running DNS servers).

Answer (score 0):

The DNS is a hierarchical system, and to get your own DNS server started, it only needs to know that the DNS servers which are authoritative for the root zone (.) are `a.root-servers.net`, `b.root-servers.net`, ... upto `m.root-servers.net`. Of course, to actually be able to talk to these servers, at least one of their IP addresses has to be provided.

There is no need to download a list with "all" information available. The root servers will point your DNS servers to the servers which are auhoritative for the top level domain you are looking for, which in turn will point you to the DNS servers responsible for the domain you want. This process will continue until you find the server that can answer your query.

IANA provides a [root hints file](http://www.iana.org/domains/root/files) containing the names and ip addresses of all the root servers.

Note (some of) these 13 root servers are actually geographically distributed clusters of servers. ICANN operates `l.root-servers.net`.

Comment: Okay, maybe I said my question wrong, what if I would like to host my own private root server using a dump of ICANNs list. Assume that I absolutely want no communication between them and myself.

Effectively, I'm basically asking how I can get a Hosts file of the entire indexed internet.

Comment: I was afraid that was what you were asking :-) Do you mind me asking "Why?!?!" Even if we could generate this file, it would be out of date in a matter of seconds. DNS was introduced because it was no longer feasible to use such a file.

Comment: Because I have a feeling that I should have my own list. Something tells me now that IANA will soon be no longer regulated by the US, it will be subject to assaults from both the ICANN and the Trans-Pacific Partnership.

I'm basically attempting to create a prophylactic in the event this happens.

Comment: "it would be out of date within seconds" well from what I understand, google DNS is only updated every 48 hours or so making this assumption moot. I realize what an xy question is but Instead of inferring the intent or worthiness of the question, it would be more helpful just to provide an answer. If you had your own list, your individual requests would be private without the need of encryption. Also, it would be faster to get a response without outside network congestion. There are millions of reasons why and answering this simple question would provide an answer for all of them.